# How to use imacros to reload recaptcha frame to load new captcha?

Tags: javascript, iframe, recaptcha, imacros

I need to use imacros to reload recaptcha frame in this image to load new captcha, everyone, plz help:
Link to the captcha: https://www.mytrainerrewards.com/login/

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMfhv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:grecaptcha.reset();
```